# How to control data listing of JSON Data for Handlebarsjs templating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

Please look at to my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rousnay/rVnsJ/

Everything is working good. its giving me list of 10 movies from external JSON source. 
But i want to limit this movie listing. i want to show only first 5 movies in output. 
how can i do this? 
Can anyone help me with `jsfiddle` example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned object is an array. Use `splice()` to remove all elements whose index greater than given index:

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rVnsJ/2/

Comment: Wooow.. you people rockz! but if i want to listing 5 to 10 movies then what will be the code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add slice to the returned array

```
$('#featuresr').html(template(data1.slice(Math.max(data1.length - 5, 1))));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmindel/rVnsJ/1/

Comment: you answer is very useful but it is listing 5 to 10, not 1 to 5 :)